# React InstantSearchNext, Next.js App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, algolia, react-instantsearch

I've been following how to configure instantsearch React with Next.js App Router here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/server-side-rendering/react/#app-router-experimental and I've done this successfully in my app.

What im wondering is:

1. Can i move `<InstantSearchNext>` so that it wraps my entire app?
2. If I move it, will SSR break since now I will have to put use client around my entire app?

This topic is not covered in the docs so i would appreciate if someone could clarify it for me.

Thanks.